# change date format in datetimepicker plugin?

Tags: jquery

how to change to australian date format for this example?
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: australian??do you mean language or date format? like what?

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy , date format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 jQuery(".ClassName").datetimepicker({
        showSecond: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
 });
```

You can define any date format above.