# How to show date in a different format

Tags: jquery

When I want to get the value in datepicker I use the following

```
var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

But suppose user in India and I want to put the value in textbox using

```
$("#datepicker").val(date);
```

However, this is the value:

```
Wed Feb 23 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)   [first]
```

I want to show them

```
24-02-2011  [second]
```

How can I put second instead of first in jQuery UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094039/change-date-format-in-datetimepicker-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the value of the DOM element, use the datepicker's [`setDate` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate), so it has a chance to format the date.